# Calculate without operator order

Tags: c#, .net, math, operators

Is there some function in C# which could let me calculate ignoring the order of operators? I mean that `2 + 6 / 2` results `4` instead of `5`.

Comment: No, you would have to roll your own expression calculator.

Comment: That's not just the order of C# operators, that's the order of mathematical operators.  In every construct of math, 2+6/2 resolves to 5.  What you're proposing doesn't exist in C# by default because it doesn't exist in the world by default, you'd have to write your own.

Comment: You could maybe use something like NRefactory to rework expressions, inserting braces, and the calculate them.

Comment: Where are these expressions? Are they part of your code, and you want the compiler to interpret them differently?  Or are you accepting input strings from the user, and interpreting these strings as arithmetic expressions?  If it is the latter, then you can parse the string and interpret it however you want.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you try to overload these operators, that does not change precedence. Many programming languages (include C#) use precedence levels that conform to the order commonly used in mathematics,

As David [*mentioned*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21063217/calculate-wihout-priorities/21063310#comment31673904_21063217), this is not only about C#. It is also about [Mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics). I don't think this is possible in C# except writing your own mathematical operators (which sounds extremly hard and complex to me).

From [`7.2.2 Operator overloading`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691324%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> User-defined operator implementations always take precedence over
>   predefined operator implementations: Only when no applicable
>   user-defined operator implementations exist will the predefined
>   operator implementations be considered.
>
> User-defined operator declarations cannot modify the syntax,
>   precedence, or associativity of an operator. For example, the /
>   operator is always a binary operator, always has the precedence level
>   specified in [Section 7.2.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), and is always left-associative.

Comment: Indeed, it's going to be *very* difficult to implement something like this, at least without it ending up being extremely complicated to support and use.  Computers are very good at doing math, but they're not very good at breaking math.

Comment: @David: I wouldn't necessarily agree, since expressions are not directly calculated on CPU or something like that. While creating your own parser it is as easy to introduce "unusual" priorities and behaviour as to do it the common way (sans maybe examples ;))., e.g. you can resolve shift/reduce conflicts other way. Other thing is, whether it is worth it in this case, but is hard to tell without further details.

Comment: And here's one example of this approach: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/178187/how-to-add-precedence-to-lalr-parser-like-in-yacc

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible as value integer types are built in to C# and you can't even modify their behavior. Why would you even want to do that? You can use parentheses to prioritize, e.g. (2+6)/2

Answer (score 0):

Given that you can't override the precedence behavior of c# operators i'd create my own expression calculator.

From your question i believe your expressions will always be `number` `operator` `number` and  outputs a `number`

Therefore you can then pick your last `number` and process it with the following `operator` `number` and so on so on.....

Two different approaches come to my mind:

1. take a string as input and parse it
2. take a `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` and parse it from here
3. There are several extensible math expression calculators for c#. Just a matter of google it and see if it can fit your needs.

Nevertheless i'd love to hear from you why you need such behavior. Is it academic?

Answer (score 0):

Operator overloading does not allow you to change operator precedence. To achieve what you want, you'd need to implement your own parser for mathematical expressions. To support only digits 0-9 and 4 operators (+, -, *, /) is not too difficult, although time consuming if you've never written a parser before. There are plenty of tutorials on writing compilers on the Internet; they'll teach you how to write a simple tokenizer, and then how to interpret the stream of tokens. In your case, you only have to deal with digits and operators, which makes this job a lot easier than implementing an entire language.

EDIT: actually, to write a parser ignoring operator precedence is actually a lot easier than implementing BODMAS.